# what freeware tool for java source code review?

Tags: java, code-review

I need freeware tool for source code review for my application which used WebSphere Portal and Java as technology. Please provide me relevant information or links regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you're unlikely to get a free tool to do full code reviews of enterprise applications as Static analysis tools tend to be complex and pretty expensive.

That said there are some things you could look at which do address Java and could be of use to you.

1. [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/)
2. [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)
3. [Lapse+](https://code.google.com/p/lapse-plus/downloads/list)

would be good places to start looking.  also some other options from [this list](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-analyzers) could be helpful.